# ASP.NET MVC - Enum not being sent to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDropListFor that looks like this:

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("FilterListingsWorkflow", "Listing",
    new {
        categoryguid = Model.SelectedCategoryGuid,
        workflowstatus = Model.SelectedWorkflowStatus,
        entityName = Model.EntityName,
    },
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "listingTable",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
    {
        <p>Filter listings by Workflow Status:</p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>
            Model.SelectedWorkflowStatus,
            Enum.GetValues(typeof (WorkflowStatus))
                .Cast<WorkflowStatus>()
                .Select(v =>
                    new SelectListItem {
                        Text = v.ToString(),
                        Value = ((int) v).ToString()
                }),
            new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit()" })
    }
```

As you can see, there are three objects that are being sent to the controller:

- `Model.SelectedCategoryGuid`, `Model.SelectedWorkFlowStatus` and `EntityName`.

`WorkFlowStatus` is an enum, and for some reason, whenever I click on any of the enums in the DropDownList, it always comes out to be the FIRST one.

I have three Enum values which get inserted in to the DropDownList which are:

- Draft, Published and Archived.

So, whenever I click on any one of them and when I hover over the variable in the Controller, I see that the parameter variable: `workflowstatus` is always Draft (which is the first one).

Does anyone know why the CORRECT enum isn't being passed over?

It's really bugging me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your DropDownList is `SelectedWorkflowStatus`. So make sure your controller action takes such parameter as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FilterListingsWorkflow(WorkflowStatus selectedWorkflowStatus)
{
    ...
}
```

That's where you will get the correct value. I can see that you are setting some route values for your form:

```
new {
    categoryguid = Model.SelectedCategoryGuid,
    workflowstatus = Model.SelectedWorkflowStatus,
    entityName = Model.EntityName,
}
```

But don't look the `workflowStatus` parameter in your action. This guy will contain the old value, the one that was hardcoded in the form when the view first rendered. The *fresh* value is stored in the `selectedWorkflowStatus` parameter coming from your DropDown.

All this being said the proper way to handle this situation is (as always in ASP.NET MVC) to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Guid SelectedCategoryGuid { get; set; }
    public WorkflowStatus WorkflowStatus { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public WorkflowStatus SelectedWorkflowStatus { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FilterListingsWorkflow(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.SelectedWorkflowStatus will contain the value from the DropDown
    // model.WorkflowStatus will contain the initial value
    ...
}
```

Also please replace:

```
m => Model.SelectedWorkflowStatus
```

with:

```
m => m.SelectedWorkflowStatus
```

in your DropDown. You don't need to capture the model in a closure.